# Bootstrap4 Как сделать что бы при сворачивание меню в кнопку, кнопка располагалась слева?

Tags: bootstrap, navigation

Есть горизонтальное меню растянутое по всей ширине .content
При сворачивание кнопка находиться по середине, а нужно что бы была слева.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Стандартным способом например.

1. Добавить class на кнопку и для этого класса в стилях прописать
   нужное расположение.
2. В JavaScript вешать этот класс при клике на сворачивание (при
   необходимости убирать класс при разворачивании)

Например с помощью bootstrap:
по центру

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-1">
        //кнопка
        </div>
</div>
```

слева

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12">
        //кнопка
        </div>
</div>
```

Соответственно нужно вешать убирать класс col-1 и col-12 в этом случае.